# Django add contrib.messages from custom middleware

Tags: django, message, middleware

I have implemented a custom middleware that check for certain fields in a user's profile. The fields are not required at sign up (in order to make it quick and easy for a user to sign up), however, I would prefer that they fill them out.

My middleware checks if they are set. If not, it notifies the user via a message. I ran into two problems.

1. Whenever I submit a posted form, because no template displays the messages, the middleware would add the message a second time since the middleware was called when the message was posted and after the redirect it was called again.

   I solved this problem by iterating through the messages in my middleware and checking if the message I am about to add is already in there. If yes, it doesn't add it again.
2. When a user fixes the problem by updating their profile, on the very next page load, the messages are still there. After that though, everything works. At the beginning of my middleware, I actually put a check that returns None if the request was posted (I would have thought this would solve both problems, but it didn't solve either).

Any idea how to solve the 2nd issue? Is there a better way to solve my first one?

Thanks.

Edit:

Is there a way to clear the messages in a view? I've tried iterating through them (without storage.used=False) and they are still there. I would expect that this would solve both my problems.

Answer (score 2):

Yoy can use sticky messages of https://github.com/AliLozano/django-messages-extends that is one storage that only keeps messages in request instead save in session

Answer (score 0):

So, are you using `django.contrib.messages` to store permanent notices? It's intended for showing one-time notifications, where the user sees the message once and then it goes away. The type of things it's meant for are messages like, "Form edited successfully."

As far as getting rid of messages in a user's message stack are concerned: any time you use a `RequestContext` (discussed [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext)) to render a template, all messages will be flushed (whether they are actually shown on the page or not).

I'm not totally sure this is the answer you're actually after, and I'm a bit confused by your question. However, I'm somewhat sure you're using messages outside its intended purpose, which is likely why you're running into trouble.

Comment: The messages are not permanent. However, they will likely be more than one-time-messages. The idea is to check for errors in profiles and check if they have verified their email and let them know until they have.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [process_reponse()](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/?from=olddocs#process-response) method of Middleware to add the message. By that time, you would know whether to show the message to user or not depending on whether his profile now has the field filled in.

Consider using django.contrib.messages. May be you do not want to show "fill in the XYZ field" message on all requests, but only on few pages, say whenever user logs in or views his profile page.

Answer (score 0):

Just place logic that creates messages to [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS) instead of middleware. Modify request and return empty dict.